# Relationship between borders of closure

Tags: general-topology

The boundary $B(A)$ of a set $A$ is the set of points that belong to neither the interior of $A$ nor the interior of $A'$ (the complement of $A$). Let $\overline{A}$ denote the closure of a set $A$. I would like to know what we can say about $B(A)$ and $B(\overline{A})$.

Suppose $x\in B(\overline{A})$. Then $x$ is a limit point of $\overline{A}$ and a limit point of $(\overline{A})'$. Since $(\overline{A})'\subseteq A'$, $x$ is also a limit point of $A'$. Also, since $\overline{A}$ is closed, a limit point of $\overline{A}$ is a limit point of $A$. So $x\in B(A)$. This means $B(\overline{A})\subseteq B(A)$.

What about the other direction? Is it true that $B(A)\in B(\overline{A})$? My guess is that it's not, but I can't come up with a counterexample.

Comment: There are sets such that the equality holds. For instance, a set is called *regular open* if $U=$int$\overline U$ or, equivalently, $U$ is the interior of some closed set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if $A$ is the set of rational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$?

Then the closure of $A$ is the entire line, which has empty boundary. However, the boundary of $A$ itself contains every point on the line.